# Empty folders without changing folder's Last Modified Date

Tags: file, directory

I wish to delete the contents of a handful of folders on my Linux Mint PC but I want to retain the Last Modified Date of the folder as it existed before deleting the files. This would be equivalent to noting the Last Modified Date of the folder, deleting the contents of the folder and then using the touch command to restore the folder date back to what it was before deleting its contents.

Can this be done as a single CLI command, and if so, how please?

I haven't tried anything to achieve this as I have no idea where to start.

Thanks

Comment: See this https://askubuntu.com/questions/385370/how-to-modify-the-directory-date